# difference between matching graph and induced matching graph

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone explain the definition of the domination Induced matching (DIM)
graph by figures to me? I know that a domination Induced matching graph of G is an induced matching that dominates every edge of G, but I can't imagine this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can help you
A matching M of G is a dominating induced matching (say a DIM) of G if every edge of G is either in M or has a common end-vertex with exactly one edge in M. A DIM is also called an efficient edge domination set.
Not all graphs have a DIM, for instance the cycle with four vertices C4 has no DIM. The DIM problem asks whether a given graph has a dominating induced matching.[image]

A graph with a DIM $M = \{12,34,56,78\}$.

---

[On the dominating induced matching problem: Spectral results and sharp bounds](https://ria.ua.pt/bitstream/10773/18244/3/1-s2.0-S0166218X16000263-main.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that M={1-2,3-4,5-6,7-8}?

Comment: I have another question. Is the dim(G)=4?( I mean the size of DIM set in your example)

Comment: A matching $M$ is a set of edges.here as you can see in the graph, $M=\{12,34,56,78\}$ ($12$  i.e. the edge between vertex $1$ and vertex $2$) is a matching and other edges of graph have a end-vertex with exactly one edge in M so M is a DIM and $|M|=4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, W.R.P.S.

Comment: Is it ok if you help me to find the minimum weight of the roman edge domination function for the graph in your example?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think minimum weight is $7$ when $E_2=\{1-9,6-10,8-11\}$ , $E_1=\{3-4\}$ , $E_0 = E(G)\setminus (E_2\cup E_1)$

Comment: Ok, but the definition of roman edge domination is that every edge e with f(e)=0 must be adjacent to some edge e' with f(e')=2.